# How do I write the sql query for removing product item from user's favourite list

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables Products, Users and favourite and I need to *write a query to remove the product from user's favourite list*. I am confused as I know I need to DELETE and INNER JOIN but I need to remove a row from the product table that is present in the favourites but it should not be removed from the entire database. I do not really know how to phrase it. I hope someone can help thank you.

Product table relevant fields (all the products available)

productid |
productname |
productdescription |
productcost

Users table relevant fields

userid |
username |
useremail

Favourite table fields

favouriteid |
usersfavouriteid (Foreign key to Users) |
productsfavoriteid (Foreign key to Product) |

Much help appreciated thank you!

Comment: Sample data -- before and after -- would clarify what you really want to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the id of the user and product that you want to delete, no need to join, you can just do:

```
delete from favourite where productsfavoriteid = @productid and usersfavouriteid  = @userid
```

If, for example, you need to delete by *product name*, you can use the `delete ... from ... join ...` syntax like so:

```
delete f
from favourite f
inner join product p 
    on  f.productsfavoriteid = p.productid
where
    f.usersfavouriteid = @userid
    and p.productname = @productname
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but delete "f", the f is a variable ?and can just be typed in as it is? sorry quite new to sql

Comment: @chloeong: `f` is a *table alias*, that stands for the table it aliases (here, `favourite`).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you would simply do:

```
delete f from favourites
    where usersfavouriteid = ? and productsfavoriteid = ?;
```

This should not have an affect on other tables in the database.